# Finding a specific row by certain criteria? Excel MACRO, VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I have an `excel` spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
DATE                   |  PART#      | XXX    | XXX | 

2013-06-28 13:32:23    |  40240      | XXX    | XXX | 

2013-02-21 13:32:23    |  40240      | XXX    | XXX |
```

There are numerous entries, with the date being the starting point. My question is how do I find the row & column by a certain date? So if I want to know the `PART#` and other attributes for `2013-06-28 13:32:23`, how can I find it?

My `MACRO` creates a new sheet, styles it and then transfers the text over from the old sheet. The problem is with the transferring of the text. I want to specify which row to get the text from to generate the report.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The following will find all rows where the search value is found:

```
Sub getVal()
    Dim searchRange As range
    Dim result As range
    Dim rangeStart As String

    Set searchRange = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set result = searchRange.Find(After:=searchRange(1), _
        What:="6/28/2013  1:32:23 PM", _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not result Is Nothing Then
        rangeStart = result.Address

        Do
            MsgBox (" row " & result(0).Row & " " & result.Address)
            Set result = searchRange.FindNext(After:=result(1))

        Loop While Not result Is Nothing And rangeStart <> result.Address
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End Sub
```